# Stop Ember helper rendering inside div

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember helper which is literally defined as this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-title="{{text}}"></span>
```

It's used to render a Bootstrap tooltip. It renders the following HTML:

```
<div id="ember572" class="ember-view">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
       data-title="<script id='metamorph-35-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>
           When a project is archived, no new items can be created in it.
           <script id='metamorph-35-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>" 
           data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="tooltip416856">
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I stop the helper rendering the containing div?

Comment: Can you put the code on how u render the tooltip?

Comment: It's just Bootstraps tooltip. If I place that span directly into a template (but not in the helper) that extra div is not generated.

Comment: Post the helper code or better create a failing demo at emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: is it really a helper or a component? if component, then the answer will be easier

Comment: It's a helper - could it be a component?

Answer (score 4):

Create a `Component` with `tagName: 'span'` instead of `<span>` in it's template:

Component:

```
App.TooltipElementComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle', 'data-placement', 'data-title']
});
```

Now, you can use following:

```
{{tooltip-element data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-title='When a project is archived, no new items can be created in it.'}}
```

Which produces following HTML:

```
<span id="ember257" class="ember-view" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-title="When a project is archived, no new items can be created in it."></span>
```

Notice you can still use bindings(`data-title=text`):

```
{{tooltip-element data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' data-title=text}}
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kolonesixu/2/edit)